# undefined method `merge' for 2:Fixnum

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i get the following error

undefined method `merge' for 2:Fixnum

for the code

```
f.check_box "page[group_ids][]", g.id
```

please, suggest solution for this.

thanks

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You should use `check_box_tag` instead of `f.check_box`.

```
check_box_tag "page[group_ids][]", g.id
```

The difference is `f.check_box` is for model-bounded forms and the value supplied to the check box is implicit from the given model and doesn't need to be provided.

Comment: This is the reason that error is appearing, though: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6636888/2948832