# Rails hidden field undefined method 'merge' error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, hidden-field

I wanna do something like this in rails

Here is what I have so far in rails:

```
<%= form_for @order do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :service, "test" %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

But then I get this error:

```
undefined method `merge' for "test":String
```

How can I pass values in my hidden_field in rails?

Answer (score 419):

You should do:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :service, :value => "test" %>
```

`hidden_field` expects a hash as a second argument

Comment: It is kind of inconsistent as we also write `<%= hidden_field_tag :service, "test" %>` when not using `form_for |f|` ...

Answer (score 55):

You are using a hidden_field instead of a hidden_field_tag. Because you are using the non-_tag version, it is assumed that your controller has already set the value for that attribute on the object that backs the form. For example:

controller:

```
def new
  ...
  @order.service = "test"
  ...
end</pre>
```

view:

```
<%= form_for @order do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :service %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 27):

It works fine in Ruby 1.9 & rails 4

```
<%= f.hidden_field :service, value: "test" %>
```

Answer (score 3):

A version with the new syntax for hashes in ruby 1.9:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :service, value: "test" %>
```

Answer (score 2):

This also works in Rails 3.2.12:

`<%= f.hidden_field :service, :value => "test" %>`

Answer (score 0):

By the way, I don't use hidden fields to send data from server to browser. [Data attributes](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/) are awesome. You can do

```
<%= form_for @order, 'data-service' => 'test' do |f| %>
```

And then get attribute value with jquery

```
$('form').data('service')
```