# Using checkboxes in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox, nomethoderror

I've never used checkboxes in rails before and can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.  When I try to load my page, I get an error that says `NoMethodError in Dplans#show, undefined method "merge" for "Art":String`

Here is the code for my checkbox form on the `Dplans` `show` page:

```
<%= form_for @dplan, :url=>{ :action=>"update_distribs" } do |f| %>
<%= f.check_box :Art, 'Art' %> <b>Art</b> <br/>
<%= f.check_box :Lit, 'Lit' %> <b>Lit</b> <br/> <br/>

<div class="actions">
  <%= f.submit "Save" %>
</div>
  <% end %>
```

Art and Lit are both strings and are `attr_accessible` in `dplan`.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721058/undefined-method-merge-for-2fixnum) out, it might be the same problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second parameter to FormBuilder.check_box is a hash of HTML options.. The string you specified is not necessary. Try this instead:

```
<%= f.check_box :Art %> <b>Art</b> <br/>
<%= f.check_box :Lit %> <b>Lit</b> <br/> <br/
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried:

```
<%= f.check_box :Art %>
<%= f.check_box :Lit %>
```

Some [examples](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-check_box) for you to consider.