# How do I update the record of a Has_Many through association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have three models - `User`, `Client`, `Topic`.

**User**

```
has_many :clients
has_many :topics, :through => :clients, :uniq => true
```

**Client**

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :topics
```

**Topic**

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :clients
```

What I am trying to do is on the `edit` view of my client, change the topics that this client has.

This is the Update Action of my Clients Controller:

```
  def update
        if params[:topic_ids]
             @client = current_user.clients.find(params[:id])
             @client.topic_ids = params[:client][:topic_ids]
             @client.save
        else
             @client = current_user.clients.find(params[:id])
        end


    respond_to do |format|
      if @client.update_attributes(params[:client])
        format.html { redirect_to @client, notice: 'Client was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @client.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

This is what the log looks like:

```
Started PUT "/clients/6" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-10-07 18:56:14 -0500
Processing by ClientsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"J172mxxCX0OdxcGm4GSPv8=", "client"=>{"name"=>"Testeeee Johnson", "email"=>"testeee@johnson.com", "phone"=>"4320981234", "firm_id"=>"1", "personal_priority"=>"1", "last_contact"=>"2012-06-08", "vote"=>"1", "vote_for_user"=>"0", "next_vote"=>"2012-10-10", "vote_ii"=>"0", "vote_ii_for_us"=>"0"}, "topic_ids"=>["2"], "commit"=>"Update Client", "id"=>"6"}
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
  Client Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "clients".* FROM "clients" WHERE "clients"."user_id" = 1 AND "clients"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "6"]]
  Topic Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "topics".* FROM "topics" INNER JOIN "clients_topics" ON "topics"."id" = "clients_topics"."topic_id" WHERE "clients_topics"."client_id" = 6
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.0ms)  commit transaction
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
   (0.0ms)  commit transaction
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
   (0.0ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/clients/6
Completed 302 Found in 8ms (ActiveRecord: 0.8ms)
```

Needless to say, it doesn't update the record for `client.topics`.

How do I update the `topics` attribute of my client record?

**Edit 1**

This is how the `_form` partial looks:

```
<%= form_for(@client) do |f| %>
  <% if @client.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@client.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this client from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @client.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :firm %><br />
    <%= f.select :firm_id, Firm.all.collect { |firm| [firm.name, firm.id] }, {:include_blank => 'None'} %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
  <h4>Topics</h4>  
    <% Topic.all.each do |topic| %>
      <% checked = @client.topics.include?(topic) %>
        <%= f.label(:name, topic.name) %> <%= check_box_tag "topic_ids[]", topic.id, checked %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
.
. - reduced for brevity
.


  <br /><br />
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: What does your form look like?

Comment: Updated to include the relevant parts of the `_form`.

Comment: Suggest updating the misleading topic title - this question is about the HABTM association, not the HMT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For whatever reason, the `form` helper doesn't work with `check_box`.

So, this is the code that works:

```
<%= check_box_tag "client[topic_ids][]", topic.id, checked %>
```

According to [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721058/undefined-method-merge-for-2fixnum) for similar questions, the helper `f.check_box` is model bound and the value supplied to the checkbox is implicit from the model on the form. The issue is, I can't figure out how to get the implicit value of the form_helper to produce the correct tag - i.e. `client[topic_ids][]`, so I have had to resort to `check_box_tag`.

Answer (score -1):

You mentioned in a comment below you would also like to add a weighting to each topic. This is no longer supported in the has_and_belongs_to_many association, so instead you should use the has_many :through association:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :clients
end

class Clients < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :client_topics
  has_many :topics, :through => :clients_topics
end

# Create this table like any other, with a "weight" field
class ClientsTopics < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :client
  belongs_to :topic
end

class Topics < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :clients_topics
  has_many :clients, :through => :clients_topics
end
```

Now your update will need to delete all existing clients_topics, then loop through the passed topic_ids and weights and add them to the client like this:

```
def update
  if params[:topic_ids]
     @client = current_user.clients.find(params[:id])

     @client.clients_topics.delete_all

     params[:client][:topic_ids].each_with_index do |topic_id, index|
       weight = params[:client][:weights][index]
       @client.clients_topics.create!(:topic_id => topic_id, :weight => weight)
     end

  else
     @client = current_user.clients.find(params[:id])
  end

  (etc...)
end
```

Comment: Is this setup via a polymorphic association?

Comment: I don't get why I would have to use an each block to delete the topics, that seems a bit hacky. Doesn't Rails have something built in to manage these types of relationships?

Comment: You can use delete_all to delete the topics associated with the client, but Rails will leave the record and just set the client_id to nil, which is usually not desirable.

Comment: No, this isn't a polymorphic association. It is basically the same as the has_and_belongs_to_many association, but the clients_topics table is explicitly created and referenced, rather than having it opaquely used. The other advantage of this is that you can add other fields to the clients_topics table, for instance, a weighting for how important each topic is to that client.

Comment: Hrmm...interesting Max, because that's exactly what I need to do. Add a weighting of importance. Kinda freaky that you said that!

Comment: Max, how do I generate the join table `ClientsTopics`? Like a regular model? `rails g model ClientsTopics`? I already have a `clients_topics` table - which was made for the HABTM. Am I better off dropping that table and re-doing everything from scratch?

Comment: Michael, yes, you generate the ClientsTopics join table as a regular table and add a regular model for it. The reason for the name is that this is the standard naming convention for HABTM tables, so unless there is a more logical name, it is good to follow this convention. Since the table already exists, there is no reason to drop it, but you can change it to add other fields like, "weight".

Comment: Max, this looks a bit non-standard & drastic to me - so I am hesitant to try this. I suspect the problem is much more basic than this general overhaul would indicate. I do appreciate your effort and time though.