# What is the proper use of the check_box form helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have two models - `Client` & `Topic`, with a HABTM relationship between them.

I am trying to generate a series of checkboxes of the topics, on the Client `form` partial.

This is what I am doing:

```
<% Topic.all.each do |topic| %>
  <% checked = @client.topics.include?(topic) %>
    <%= f.label(:name, topic.name) %> <%= f.check_box @topics, topic.id %>
<% end %>
```

This is the error I get:

```
undefined method `merge' for 1:Fixnum
```

I know one solution is to use `check_box_tag`, but that forces me to do the record updating of the associations manually.

So I would rather use the form_helper for the checkbox tag. [The docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-check_box) are a bit confusing to me.

How can I get this to work with `f.check_box`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For whatever reason, the `form` helper doesn't work with `check_box`.

So, this is the code that works:

```
<%= check_box_tag "client[topic_ids][]", topic.id, checked %>
```

According to [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721058/undefined-method-merge-for-2fixnum) for similar questions, the helper `f.check_box` is model bound and the value supplied to the checkbox is implicit from the model on the form. The issue is, I can't figure out how to get the implicit value of the form_helper to produce the correct tag - i.e. `client[topic_ids][]`, so I have had to resort to `check_box_tag`.

Answer (score 0):

The code confuses me. What `@topics` contains? If it's a collection of of `Topic` then why you  are directly accessing `Topic` model in the view? It would be:

```
@topics.each.do
```

rather than you

```
Topic.all.each
```

Moreover, you are using @topics as collection inside a loop. How check_box will generate checkbox from a collection?

Please look at the following things:

1. [accepts_nested_attributes_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html#method-i-accepts_nested_attributes_for). you will need this to set in Client model in addition to Client `has_many` Topic association
2. [fields_for](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for) Otherwise, rails will not have any idea that you want to update topic model from this same form.
3. Check [this screencasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1) to get an idea how you can make it work

Comment: Even if I change the checkbox helper to be: `f.checkbox topic, topic.id` - where the local variable is `topic`, it still gives me that Fixnum error. What am I missing?

Comment: Also the issue is not whether or not the attribute is accessible. It is. I can access the attributes if I do it from the command-line, for instance. I just don't know how to do it using `f.check_box`.

Comment: if you read the links i've given, you will get better idea. specially if you check the screencast.